# Why there are the same variables of mine with a ':' in Visual Studio auto complete list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete

What's the difference between `myVar` and `myVar:` in VS auto-complete list while working with functions. Why the second one is added to this list ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C# 4.0 introduced [named arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). This feature allows you to identify method arguments by their names instead of their position:

```
public void Foo(int bar, string quux)
{
}

// Before C# 4.0:
Foo(42, "text");

// After C# 4.0:
Foo(bar: 42, quux: "text");

// Or, equivalently:
Foo(quux: "text", bar: 42);
```

Intellisense has been updated to support that feature, that's why its autocompletion mechanism now offers both choices when a symbol accessible from the current scope has the same name as a method argument.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably when you're setting a value for a parameter when calling a method, yeah? In C# .NET 4, you can set [named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) when calling a method. This removes the need for having to enter your parameters in a set order.

```
private void MyMethod(int width, int height){
   // do stuff
}

//These are all the same:
MyMethod(10,12);
MyMethod(width: 10, height: 12);
MyMethod(heigh: 12, width: 12);
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a very cool feature. it allows your code to be more tolerant to parameter ordering changes...

Comment: and makes code more verbose. of course for some people the more dry the language is the better, but I like code to be as readable as possible.

Comment: @Daniel Rose - I'd rather have it less tolerant to name changes.  If you change the order of two parameters with the same or compatible types, it will compile without error, but function incorrectly.

Comment: @Mystere Man I did some more checking. Similar to optional parameters, it is syntactic sugar for the compiler. That means the order is compiled into the MSIL. So if you change the order, all clients will continue to use the old order until you recompile them!

Comment: @Daniel Rose - Yes?  And?  That's what build systems and dependancy scanning is for.  If your build system actually allows binaries to be incorrectly versioned, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: @Mystere Man That's all very nice if you have an internal API, but it's different if you have public API which is used by third parties (think of a control by a company such as Telerik or the .NET framework). Any changes to the order of the parameters is a breaking change (as before), and additionally, any change to the parameter name is a breaking change (that changed from before 4.0). So no more fixing that parameter name widht unless you want to potentially break all clients.

Comment: @Daniel Rose - If you have a public API, you have to take more measures than that, since you API is documented, and thus cannot easily change.  That's a totally different animal.  You can't depend on people using named paramters at all, so it makes no difference.

Comment: @Mystere Man Yes. Basically the feature has its upsides and downsides, and you have to be aware of them, especially if you have a public API.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the others wrote: The first one is a (local) variable or field, while the last one is the name of the parameter of the called method. In code:

```
private void MyFirstMethod(int myVar)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myVar);
}

private void MySecondMethod(int myVar)
{
    MyFirstMethod(myVar); // Call with the value of the parameter myVar
    MyFirstMethod(myVar: myVar); // Same as before, but explicitly naming the parameter

    MyFirstMethod(5); // Call with the value 5
    MyFirstMethod(myVar: 5); // Same as before, but explicitly naming the parameter
}
```